# Class with sharing get access just to records from the current user?

Tags: trigger, sharing-rule, apex-sharing

Need to update related records based in a field value from the parent record. If I use with sharing in class, just the records that the current user has access will be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct. You won't be able to query records the user does not have access to, nor will you be able to update records the user has read-only access to. The four main permissions, Create, Read, Update, and Delete (CRUD) are honored when using `with sharing`, but Field Level Security (FLS) is *not* honored, so you need to make sure to use [Security.stripInaccessible](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Security.htm) if you want to prevent updating fields the user does not have edit permission on.

Comment: So if the class has a query that get the related records from that parent record, the records retrieved from that query depends on the user that triggered the class?

Comment: @user87331 Yes, depending on the user's sharing for those child records, the query will return just the children they can see.

Comment: sfdcfox Thank you for all the help, I really appreciate it.